# Geopandas not plotting correct colors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

My Geopandas DataFrame has 3 polygons and 9 points with `color_rgba` column computed with `matplotlib.colors.to_rgba` function:

```
import contextily as ctx
import geopandas as gpd

(...)
rdf[['geometry','color_rgba']]
```

[image]

When I try to plot the map something odd happens with 3 of the 9 points:

- They inherit the color (dark) of the polygons and I can't understand
  how.
- They should be all white as per the `color_rgba` column.

Code:

```
ax = rdf.plot(figsize=(20, 20), markersize = 100, edgecolor='k', color=rdf['color_rgba'])
xlim = ([-9.30, -9.00])
ylim = ([38.60, 38.87])
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=df.crs, url=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLite)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

Comment: **[Don't Post Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)**. Always provide a [mre], with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. It's likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You're discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(15).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246).

Comment: This is a known bug in GeoPandas when having mixed geometry types and passing the colors like this (see https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1379). I think the easiest workaround for now is to plot the points and polygons separately (you can subset the single dataframe, once for the polygons, once for the points, and plot each)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- as noted by @joris there is a known bug.  I intend to work on a PR to fix so wanted this as a test case as well
- have created geometry similar to that you have shown as screen shot in question
- in interim, the following can be used as a work around

```
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    "seg", rdf["color_rgba"].unique(), N=len(rdf["color_rgba"].unique())
)
ax = rdf.plot(
    figsize=(20, 20), markersize=100, edgecolor="k", column="color_rgba", cmap=cmap
)
```

#### full code

```
import geopandas as gpd
import contextily as ctx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shapely.wkt, shapely.geometry
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# reconstruct some geometry as not provided in question
lisbon = "POLYGON ((-9.2298356 38.69532759999999, -9.2159024 38.6913994, -9.1252283 38.70985619999998, -9.0932228 38.74978019999999, -9.0863328 38.79622539999999, -9.0993972 38.79637019999999, -9.0991256 38.7752176, -9.1450919 38.788146499999996, -9.1498877 38.7958538, -9.1831151 38.7785452, -9.2090617 38.7549077, -9.2079549 38.7241641, -9.2298356 38.69532759999999))"
b = np.array(shapely.wkt.loads(lisbon).bounds)
rdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {
        "geometry": [
            shapely.wkt.loads(lisbon).buffer(0.02, cap_style=2, join_style=2),
            shapely.wkt.loads(lisbon),
            shapely.wkt.loads(lisbon).buffer(-0.02, cap_style=2, join_style=2),
        ]
        + [
            shapely.geometry.Point(xy)
            for xy in zip(np.linspace(*b[[0, 2]], 9), np.linspace(*b[[1, 3]], 9))
        ],
        "color_rgba": [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1)]
        + [(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) for _ in range(9)],
    },
    crs="epsg:4386",
)

# ax = rdf.plot(figsize=(20, 20), markersize = 100, edgecolor='k', color=rdf['color_rgba'])
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    "seg", rdf["color_rgba"].unique(), N=len(rdf["color_rgba"].unique())
)
ax = rdf.plot(
    figsize=(20, 20), markersize=100, edgecolor="k", column="color_rgba", cmap=cmap
)

xlim = [-9.30, -9.00]
ylim = [38.60, 38.87]
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs=rdf.crs, url=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLite)
ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]